# Pyspark: Remove outliers from a pyspark dataframe based on type of department

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, databricks, outliers

I have a pyspark dataframe which have 3 departments. I have three different lower and upper bounds for three departments. I am trying to remove outlier from all the three departments all together based on filters of lower and upper bounds.

The code I have tried is

```
dept_list=(joined_read.select('Dept').distinct().rdd.map(lambda x : x[0]).collect())

for dept in dept_list:

  upper_bound=joined_read.filter(F.col('Dept')==dept).select('upperbound').collect()[0][0]
  lower_bound=joined_read.filter(F.col('Dept')==dept).select('lowerbound').collect()[0][0]

  filt_df=df.withColumn('outlier',when((F.col('Age')>=lower_bound)&\
                                                (F.col('Age')<=upper_bound)&\
                                                (F.col('Dept')==dept),"0"))\
                                          .otherwise("1"))
```

df here is a dataframe with employee details like dept age salary etc.

joined_read is created by grouping over dept and aggregating over age

This returns no value, if there is any other way to achieve the same it will help too.
Each dept has a different outlier criteria and hence need to run outlier removal 3 times for 3 different Dept.

Final output required is a single pyspark dataframe with all the data of all departments but outlier removed for all departments.

Edit**
The joined read dataframe- is

| Department | Mean_Age | Std_dev | upperbound | lowerbound |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dept1 | 38 | 7 | 52 | 24 |
| Dept2 | 43 | 4 | 51 | 35 |
| Dept3 | 32 | 6 | 44 | 22 |

Dept 3 has lower bound 22 as min age working after college.
This is not the real data but a manipulated one for confidentiality.

Comment: Please provide 'joined_read' dataframe and where does 'df' come from in for loop?

Comment: you could do all of this without loops, if you can join the 2 dataframes on `dept` field

Comment: @MohammadSunny I have added  the new information in the question, df here is a dataframe with employee details like dept age salary etc.
joined_read is created by grouping over dept and aggregating over age

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula Ye it is databricks but I think its aws based one

Comment: @samkart Yes I believe with udf and joining df could work, I was hoping to find a solution which takes spark capabilities or a single line coder inside the loop, basically things other than udf and joining DF, UDF on this data is too slow

Comment: why would this UDF be required?

Comment: can you posta solution mine doesnt seem to work